# feather data storage library for python 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dataframe' error

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I am getting the following error after attempting to read in an xlsx file, write it to a dataframe using feather, then read in that same dataframe using feather and display the results using df.head()

```
import pandas as pd
import feather
v = pd.__version__
#--- read in excel data

in_path = '/Users/me/Documents/python/data/FGS2000-2015.xlsx'
out_path = '/Users/me/Documents/python/data/mydata.feather'
df = pd.read_excel(in_path)

#--- write pandas dataframe to disk
feather.write_dataframe(df,out_path)

#--- read dataframe from disk
data = feather.read_dataframe(out_path)
data.head()
```

> 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dataframe' error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by doing:

```
pip install feather-format
```

Instead of:

```
pip install feather
```

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to restart pyCharm for changes to take effect (I didnt have to restart after pipping feather, but had to restart after re-pipping feather-format)